# What is the result string (!<!>) of yaml-cpp emit?

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

I made simple example code to demonstrate YAML load/dump with yaml-cpp(ver 0.5.2) by referencing yaml-cpp tutorial. Dump result file was not what I expected.

- Manually edited YAML file

```yaml
# config.yaml file
lastLogin: 1441030476
password: "pass1234"
username: "admin"
```

- Example program

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
int main()
{
  const char config_yaml[] = "config.yaml";
  YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile(config_yaml);

  if (config["lastLogin"]) {
    std::cout << "Last logged in: " << config["lastLogin"].as<int>() << "\n";
  }

  const std::string username = config["username"].as<std::string>();
  const std::string password = config["password"].as<std::string>();
  std::cout << "username: '" << username << "'" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "password: '" << password << "'" << std::endl;
  config["lastLogin"] = (int)time(0);
  std::ofstream fout(config_yaml);
  fout << config;
  return 0;
}
```

- Generated dump file

```yaml
# config.yaml file
lastLogin: 1441030476
password: !<!> pass1234
username: !<!> admindvp
```

As you see in above generated file, the value of string is changed from quoted to `"!<!>"` prefixed string.
  My question is what does mean `"!<!>"` in prior to string value in dump result.
And how I make yaml-cpp dumps quote string with above example.
The Nodejs yamljs module can't loads the string properly, it recognizes it as null, so `"!<!>"` notation must not be for string.

Comment: Maybe this will trigger that someone will invent an N+1th (N >> 4) text syntax for data files...*yawns* And for all those N "technologies", there will be 50%-80% completed tool chains and libraries. And each is of course arguably better than the other.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bug in yaml-cpp. See [the issue](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/202) on the project site.

Comment: That bug was reported 2 years ago on version 0.5.1. Did somebody not fix it yet?

Comment: No, I didn't fix it yet, since I have a day job. Patches welcome :)

Comment: Hi, you are an owner of the library in github. I confirmed your answer. How it comes nobody touch that bug. Is the world ever busy right now?

Comment: Looks like in newer (0.6.3?) yaml-cpp this is fixed in https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/commit/d0250400496b6ac61f672bdad116c36c24383dd8